# How to include lightning record page into vf?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-connect

I have created lightning record page using lightning app builder,Now I want to include that into my page when they click button.
Here is my code:

```
 <div id="tab-scoped-7-content"
     class="slds-tabs--scoped__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel"
     aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-7__item">
     <apex:include pageName="" />
 </div>
```

This is my lightning record page,I want to include this page into activities tab.
[image]

when I click the activities tab,lightning record page should open.
Here is the screenshot,
[image]

Comment: You have created a new Rcord Page for activites?

Comment: yes(First image) in lightning,i want to link this to activities tab